# Are some of the Civ 5 achievements bugged?

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

I seem to be having trouble getting the Magellan achievement, but I see a LOT that still have 0% on the global statistics for the game. Does anyone know if some of the achievements are bugged, or if it's just that the instructions are esoteric and unclear in their descriptions?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good money is on the achievements being either bugged, have not been "activated" for earning, or something else entirely.

At any rate, they are currently un-earnable, though if the patch last week fixed them, all bets are off (and there's some evidence that it did, see comment below).

Comment: Magellan is currently at 0.1% achieved, so it's at least possible now  - I'm fairly sure it was bugged, and fixed in the 22nd October 2010 update, since it was at 0% before that (though there's no mention of it that I can see in the patch notes http://store.steampowered.com/news/4528/ )

Comment: @therefromhere -- yes, I agree with you, though I probably could have made that more clear.

Comment: Almost all achievements only work in Singleplayer and, let's face it, that gets boring very quickly. I only play Multiplayer with friends, hence most achievements are still locked.

Answer (score 1):

I just won my first Victory with Harald of Denmark. No achievement.

My berserkers are currently headed towards Firaxis.

Also, I won on a huge map, by taking out everyone else... apart from the ones that died to others (like poor Gandhi who spawned next to the nice and peaceful Alexander the Great). I have a lot of heavily upgraded and very experienced berserkers...

Note: I specifically sent a ski infantry to get the biathlon one, worked right fine, a few turns before winning. So the achievement functionality is just fine, it's only working... not always.

Conclusion: two years later, the game is still buggy on achievements :D

Comment: Jut got the biathlon.  Appears that fast movement cannot be active.

Answer (score -4):

I asked a similar question earlier. to help answer your question because I had to go to Steam's help section to get an answer

Steam's direct Help team explained to me that achievements can only be obtained when all game mods are turned off this includes any Downloadable content (DLC) (add-on's) that are not required for the achievement.

So, for instance, if you are not trying to obtain the Babylonian campaign DLC achievements you would need to have that Downloadable content DLC unchecked when starting the game where you are attempting to get the achievement.

Also and again, any game modifiers cannot be used when the game is being built to get the achievements as well.

To reiterate one more time from the start.

1. You just loaded up Civ5 you're at the start screen go into DLC and uncheck all content that is unrelated to the achievement you are trying to obtain.
2. DO NOT go into the MODS section
3. Now set up your game choosing the required civilization for the achievement and then go for it. Good Luck

I had completed several of the achievements listed on the Steam achievements list many times and could not for the life of me understand why I was not getting the achievements from Steam. Then today I asked them directly and now I know why. I was using mods and also had some of the DLC's checked. I went and removed them all as Steam suggested and the very first time I went for a specific achievement I got it! Anyways, I hope this helped you.